# Best way to manage Dialogs in React

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui, react-hooks

I wonder if there is not a better way to manage the open and close of Dialogs in a functional component? You can find an example below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import EditDialog from './EditDialog';
import DeleteDialog from './DeleteDialog';


const ContactCard = ({ contact }) => {
  const [editOpen, setEditOpen] = useState(false);
  const [deleteOpen, setDeleteOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleEditOpen = () => {
    setEditOpen(true);
  };
  const handleEditClose = () => {
    setEditOpen(false);
  };
  const handleDeleteOpen = () => {
    setDeleteOpen(true);
  };
  const handleDeleteClose = () => {
    setDeleteOpen(false);
  };

  const { type, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, mail } = contact;
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.main}>
        {/* All my contact informations */}
      </div>
      <EditDialog handleClose={handleEditClose} open={editOpen} />
      <DeleteDialog handleClose={handleDeleteClose} open={deleteOpen} />
    </>
  );
};

ContactCard.propTypes = {
  contact: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default ContactCard;
```

I think this is super redundant but I cannot find a nicer way to manage several different dialogs.

```
const handleEditOpen = () => {
    setEditOpen(true);
  };
  const handleEditClose = () => {
    setEditOpen(false);
  };
  const handleDeleteOpen = () => {
    setDeleteOpen(true);
  };
  const handleDeleteClose = () => {
    setDeleteOpen(false);
  };
```

Many thanks for your time and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce some of the redundancy of your code, you could set the open/close in one function, by essentially toggling the current state. I did mine inline, but you could still create a handleEdit function and toggle the state there.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [editCard, setEditCard] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setEditCard(!editCard)}>Toggle Edit</button>
      {editCard && <div>Card is open for editing</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is another example with your code. I didn't run it, but it should look something like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import EditDialog from './EditDialog';
import DeleteDialog from './DeleteDialog';


const ContactCard = ({ contact }) => {
  const [editOpen, setEditOpen] = useState(false);
  const [deleteOpen, setDeleteOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setEditOpen(!editOpen);
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setDeleteOpen(!deleteOpen);
  };

  const { type, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, mail } = contact;
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.main}>
        {/* All my contact informations */}
      </div>
      {
         editOpen && <EditDialog handleEdit={handleEdit} />
      }
      {
        deleteOpen && <DeleteDialog handleClose={handleClose} /> 
      }
    </>
  );
};

ContactCard.propTypes = {
  contact: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default ContactCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility of open the dialog should be of the main component. This way the modal is only rendered if the state property is true.
Another tip is use `<React.Fragment>` insted `<>`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import EditDialog from './EditDialog';
import DeleteDialog from './DeleteDialog';


const ContactCard = ({ contact }) => {
  const [editOpen, setEditOpen] = useState(false);
  const [deleteOpen, setDeleteOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleEditOpen = () => {
    setEditOpen(!editOpen);
  };

  const handleDeleteOpen = () => {
    setDeleteOpen(!deleteOpen);
  };

  const { type, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, mail } = contact;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={classes.main}>
        {/* All my contact informations */}
      </div>
      {
         editOpen && <EditDialog handleClose={handleEditOpen} />
      }
      {
        deleteOpen && <DeleteDialog handleClose={handleDeleteOpen} /> 
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ContactCard.propTypes = {
  contact: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default ContactCard;
```

Comment: This does not address the question which is asking about how to avoid the extra boilerplate code for managing the state for each dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To incapsulate logic of changing dialog opening state, I'd recommend to create separate hook:

```js
const useToggle = (defaultValue) => {
  return useReducer((value) => !value, !!defaultValue)
}
```

This hook is basically `useState` but setState function isn't waiting for argument to update state, it updates state with the inverse of current state.

This might be useful while working with dialogs:

```js
const ContactCard = () => {
  const [editOpen, toggleEditOpen] = useToggle(false);
  const [deleteOpen, toggleDeleteOpen] = usetoggle(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.main}>
        {/* All my contact informations */}
      </div>
      {editOpen && <EditDialog handleEdit={toggleEditOpen} />}
      {deleteOpen && <DeleteDialog handleClose={toggleDeleteOpen} />}
    </>
  );
};
```